# Grant insight into

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an adjective that describes a thing that grants insight into a topic?

> the point is ___

Not "insightful" because that means showing insight, but more like "educational" except specifically for insight (perhaps intuition).

Comment: For word requests, "to ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: You may want a noun, such as *key*. You can  also use many nouns attributively  *key concept*.

Comment: “enlightening”?

Comment: @AndyBonner that's the right kind of word

Comment: 'Elucidatory' has the required meaning, but Orwell's VIth argues against using it. I like your 'grants insight into'.

Answer (score 3):

[illuminating](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/illuminating)

> giving you new information about a subject or making it easier to understand:

Answer (score 0):

The OP specifies *more like "educational."*

> The point is **revealing**.

**revealing** (adj.)

> Allowing a look at or an understanding of something inner or hidden
>
> *A revealing confession* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revealing)

> That discloses or divulges something secret or previously unknown;
> that makes **interesting or significant information** known or apparent. OED

---

> There is a **revealing** point here about someone like Weber and his
> legacy. [W. Doniger and M. C. Nussbaum; *Pluralism and Democracy in
> India*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pluralism_and_Democracy_in_India/Dh1cBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22revealing%20point%22&pg=PT91&printsec=frontcover)

> Aristotle provides a **revealing** point of contrast. [Brian Norton;
> *Fiction and the Philosophy of Happiness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fiction_and_the_Philosophy_of_Happiness/ABviUgNQ3lMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22revealing%20point%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover)
> Perhaps the most perplexing and yet **revealing** point is that all
> the men were killed; not just the Christians, but all of them — even
> the chief in some versions of the story  [Armin Geertz; *The Invention
> of Prophecy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Invention_of_Prophecy/010n4juXQRcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22revealing%20point%22&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: "revealing" in my experience contains more of a connotation that the knowledge is unfavorable to someone.  That, for instance, Weber or the person constrasted to Aristotle, is worse than expected.

Comment: @Mary *revealing* can be, but we educate ourselves-- and can gain insight--into positive *and* negative things. I don't read the OP's question as a request for one-way enlightenment. How many "prophets" in history were revealed to be false ones?