# current usage of "insightful"?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-rule

I frequently see "insightful" used to mean "provides insight", whereas I would agree with the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577571/grant-insight-into) that "revealing", "illuminating", etc. are correct usage, and that saying something like

> an experiment along the following lines would be insightful ... (*)

is incorrect.

To try to clarify the distinction:

- the traditional/dictionary sense is ["exhibiting or characterized by insight"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insightful). That could apply to a person, or to something authored by a person (["insightful analysis –– thinking that sees beyond the obvious and expresses an original thought"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/insightful))
- the new sense here is that some activity will *provide* or *grant* insight, e.g. an experiment.

I agree that these meanings aren't completely distinct (I'm having some trouble drawing a bright line); e.g., an insightful analysis could both *contain* (or *embody*) and *provide* insight. But "this experiment is insightful" feels wrong to me — I'm still trying to pin down why.

Since I don't want to be a cranky prescriptivist: is there a way to find out how the frequency of this usage has changed/is changing over time so I can decide whether this is the New Normal and I should just get used to it?

Comment: *"Is there a way to find out"?* Perhaps with [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/).

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me how to track *usage* with the n-gram viewer: if I could come up with phrases that were characteristic of each usage that would work but how would I distinguish in general between"this book is insightful" (traditional usage) and "this experiment is insightful" (new usage)? It would be useful even to have a good technical description of the difference between insightful=="has insight" vs. insightful=="provides insight" (if one exists)

Comment: It would help to know what you expect *insightful* to mean. Is the issue that you expect *insightful* to be applied to a person or a faculty of understanding, rather than an external element like an *experiment*?

Comment: Hmm.  I'm open to suggestions about how to edit this question so it "can be answered with facts and citations". "is there a way to find out how the frequency of this usage has changed/is changing over time" ... maybe not. http://viveksck.github.io/langchangetrack/data/kulkarni.pdf is interesting but doesn't look feasible for this case.  I guess I could assemble a corpus and run a Mechanical Turk experiment to quantify ...

Comment: I think I should try https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/ ...

Comment: I voted to reopen because I see the issue as one of usage (how a word is used) more than opinion (whether such usage is right or not). There are several avenues for answering, including COCA (yes) as well as usage guides and articles that mention the usage.

Comment: Hopefully "insightful" doesn't lead to a new round of "hopefully" wars.

Comment: Yes - I do think I should probably give up, but I'm still curious whether my *perception* that "insightful" didn't used to be used this way is correct.  If I have time I will dig into COCA (4900 hits from 1990 to 2012 ...)

Comment: Drifting meaning like this is common in English.

Comment: I voted this up because it is fundamentally about meanings or shift in meaning, not about how to measure shift. An opinion may be insightful. An experiment may be designed to provide insight but is not itself insightful; the results provide insight; the discussion of the results may then be insightful. I suggest the emphasis of the question should be changed to focus on the fundamental issue.

Comment: Hmm. I *don't* mean to ask "which is correct?", I *do* mean to ask about how to tell if a shift has occurred/is occurring ...

Comment: You find out by (1) consulting dictionaries (2) reading articles and papers by knowledgeable people on the word's usage, and (3) reading/searching publications that you consider authoritative or well written and that happen to use the word.

Comment: My guess is that words/expressions like 'hopefully', 'insightful', and 'beg the question' will eventually be accepted as having 2 flip-flop meanings, like 'comfortable' and 'curious', which would be consistent with the 'drifting meaning' pointed out by Barmar.